# Populate table based in select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this code to populate a table based in the select option chosen. This code works fine if the user click in the select, but not if the user uses the arrow keys.

In that case the table is not cleaned, and the data from json is populated sequentially. So, the output in table will not match the current selected option.

Any idea about this?

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $('.agencies_table').html('');
    $.getJSON("/users/agencies/" + this.value, function(data) {
        $.each(data.json_list, function(i, obj) {
            $('.agencies_table').append('<tr> <td>' + obj.label + '</td> </tr>');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: can you show a bit of html too? I'm a bit confused on the point of using .html('') and then .append(). If you are appending just the rows where are the other table tags?

Comment: Maybe the table is **agencies_table**

Comment: @LelioFaieta `$('.agencies_table').html('');` can be written `$('.agencies_table').empty();`

Comment: @mplungjan yes, i know. The point is: has the OP a structure where only table rows (those included inside the <tbody> tag) are in that div?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by `in that div` the agenices_table is likely a table or a tbody.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution you can look at is to abort the previous call

```
var xhr;
$('select').on('change', function () {
    if (xhr) {
        xhr.abort();
    }
    $('.agencies_table').html('');
    xhr = $.getJSON("/users/agencies/" + this.value, function (data) {
        $.each(data.json_list, function (i, obj) {
            $('.agencies_table').append('<tr> <td>' + obj.label + '</td> </tr>');
        });
    }).always(function () {
        xhr = undefined;
    });
});
```